How to access webdriver logs in Karate
I want to print driver performance logs in karate like we do in selenium e.g. driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll(). How can I do the same in karate framework?
Thank you
I tried * def a = script("window.performance.getEntries()") to get performance logs but I am getting error
"message":"javascript error: circular reference\n  (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.61)".

Please see if this thread provides any hints: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1786
Right now as far as I know, the "in browser" logs show up in the HTML report, but there is no way to intercept them or get them via an API. This should be easily do-able, and I suggest you contribute a PR to make this happen in Karate.

Thank you @Peter. I tried with * def a = script("Array.from(window.performance.getEntries())") and its working fine. Also I am able to filter out data using filter function. Thank you
